# Wordpress url rewriting not working 404 error while adding code to a function

Tags: wordpress, url, url-rewriting, http-status-code-404

I want to convert my link of WordPress website like:

https://www.edifybuzz.com/listing/aspam-scottish-school/?tab=content

https://www.edifybuzz.com/listing/aspam-scottish-school/content

I have already added add_rewrite_rule function in my function.php but it's not working. it's giving us a 404 error

CODE:-

```
function prefix_aboutus_rewrite_rule() {
add_rewrite_rule( '^listing/([^/]+)/content', '? 
listing=$matches[1]&tab=content', 'top' );
}

add_action( 'init', 'prefix_aboutus_rewrite_rule' );
```

displaying 404 error page

Comment: When you add a rewrite rule, you need to flush rewrite rules for wordpress use it. You can do it by going in admin to Settings > permalink and just click "save". It's flush rewrite rules. Try to reload your page after that and say us if it's work ;)

Comment: you can also see https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/flush_rewrite_rules for do this programaticaly but you you must not use flush_rewite_rules in init action

Answer (score 0):

i have solved My Problem with this code

```
add_action( 'init', function(){
    return add_rewrite_rule(
        'listing-about-us/([^/]+)/?$', // ([^/]+) takes alphanumeric, while ([0-9]+) accepts digits
        'index.php?pagename=listing-about-us&listing_id=$matches[1]',
        'top'
    );
});

add_filter('query_vars', function($v){ return array_merge(array('website'),$v); });
```